# How to power (from AC) & set varying overcurrent limits on the fly for 12 V DC motor

Tags: dc-motor, current-limiting, torque

I am trying to use a 12 V geared down (high torque, low speed) motor in an exercise application. I want to be able to roughly adjust the load akin to adding more physical weights on a traditional exercise machine. The user would be resisting the movement of something attached to the motor's physical output.

If I'm not mistaken (probably am) it seems like a way to do it would be to set the overcurrent amperage limit so that the torque is limited. A bench top power supply would work, I think, with some caveats.

I like the built in interface but have no need for voltage control. If it were just for me I wouldn't care but trying to make a rough prototype for someone.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. In general you can think of it like this:

- Constant voltage will tend to give constant speed.
- Constant current will tend to give constant torque.

For the power supply you may need to take care that the motor won't generate a high voltage back into it and blow some components. This might happen, for example, if the weights are suddenly released.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJMRJo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The circuit.*

- I1 is your current-limited power supply.
- D1 prevents backfeed into the power supply if the motor starts generating positive voltage.
- D2 snubs negative voltage when SW1 is opened.

Diodes need to be rated for the maximum motor current.

Current limit can be determined by \$ I_{max} = \frac P V \$ where the power and voltage are taken from the motor rating plate.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a fun project. You are on the right track, limiting current will definitely limit the torque. In searching for "current limiting 12V power supply" at my favorite china store I found many of them ranging from about $10 to about $60. If you get to keep the power supply I would suggest you get the bench top lab power supply and a hefty Shockley diode to shunt the output terminal to protect from back EMF. Some of the better lab supplies will have this, the cheaper ones not so. In either case it will not hurt and can only help. You will of course have to size according to the motor's current requirements. Changing voltage will also help limit the output torque. On the current limit your power supply will probably have fold back voltage (lowers voltage to control current) but there also what they call Bang-Bang which simply turn the output off, then back on effectively limiting the current. They are not so popular today because of modern electronics. The result is: your lowest torque is when your DC motor  at its highest speed with no load, conversely maximum torque is reached at zero speed with the load assuming power is at the motor's specified values.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple method how to control current for small DC motors (up to about 4A) is bellow. The motor there is rated for 1A so you choose R2 shunt equals to 1ohm what at 1A makes 1V R2 drop. So if you set with R4 the base voltage to 1.7v the motor will run at full torque.
If you set R4 to 1.2v base voltage the motor will run with 0.5A (half of rated current).

You must use a power transistor like BD... with bigger heatsink. Also, the resistors must be power types like 2W more.

[image]